# How to solve this in Access forms with Visual basic SQL server connection?

Tags: database, forms, connection, ms-access-2007, ado

I created a form that essentially show me the Orders from the familiar Northwind database, I´m using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, Microsoft Access 2007 with Visual basic (ADO), so I created the basic form, which pretty much looks like this:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/63259070@N06/7014481001/in/photostream/

Granted it is in Spanish and I'm terrible sorry but hopefully that wont hamper your ability to help me out, So as you can see there is a big main form and then there is a little form consisting of four text bars which of course are attributes or columns in a database called order details So as you can see from this relation:

flickr.com/photos/63259070@N06/6868373952/in/photostream/

You have the table orders (Pedido) and the table order details (Detalle de pedidos), what I want to do is when I click the main >>, the products show accordingly to the Orders, hopefully this will make sense when im on a order and click the sub form with the four elements, it should only show me the products, price, quantity, product id, according to the Order ID in the main form when I click the >> or << in the sub form....

So to exemplify say I have an order ID of 001 and 001 ordered three products, salt, pepper, chicken ... it should only show me that in the sub form.. Hopefully you got this I hope.. please

Here is my complete VB 6 code... again any help is well appreciated thanks...

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bn71VqxzB1W55sHcKMstCSxnIbmP5cyYWkBVnF1tzVs/edit

Comment: Master Detail is what you want, loads of examples of how to do it in Access about on google

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented a great deal with ADO in Access and I finally concluded that it is not the best technology to use when it comes forms and reports in MS Access. It's OK for connecting to data sources that can only be access through ADO, or in which there is a significant advantage to using ADO (such as speed) but in those cases you must make compromises which often require you to omit certain features or work very hard to code them. Comboboxes that use a SQL statement (as opposed to a Value List) are difficult to setup and will require you to load a separate recordset in order to fill them with options. I've found sorting to not always work properly and reliably, specifically in datasheet view forms. In short, it's a lot more work and code to make ADO work in Access forms unless you keep your forms exceedingly simple (and that often makes them clumsy to use).

What I recommend you do instead is use ODBC linked tables. This might require you to first install a SQL Server ODBC driver. After you have your linked tables setup in Access, you can then use Access as though those tables were local tables. You can use bound forms (which automatically use DAO to access data) and setting up master/detail forms is a breeze under this configuration. You can even use the wizards though I wouldn't necessarily recommend that.

If you do insist on using ADO, I recommend you experiment with setting the form's recordset to the ADO recordset. This would then be a bound form and would keep you from having to write code to move data from the recordset into the controls and vice versa. Here's some of your code modified to do that:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set con = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rs2 = Nothing

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;User ID=sa0378;password=123;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=(local);"
    con.Open


    rs.Open "SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.ShipCountry," & _
         "Orders.EmployeeID, Orders.CustomerID, Orders.ShipCity," & _
         "Orders.ShipAddress, Orders.ShipPostalCode, Orders.Freight, Orders.OrderDate," & _
         "Orders.RequiredDate, Orders.ShippedDate FROM Orders", con, _
         adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

    Set Me.Recordset = rs

End Sub
```

That code however won't setup the master/detail relationship your looking for. It will still be your job to make that happen manually by loading the correct recordset anytime the user changes to a different record on the main form. You should be able to do this on the form's Current event.